# Flutter InteractiveViewer onInteractionEnd return to scale of 1.0

Tags: flutter, dart

I'd like to have the image I am scaling return to the original scale value(1.0) when it is released.

onInteractionEnd seems like the right property to do this with but I am not sure how to access a scale property to create a function that does this.

```
      child: InteractiveViewer(
                boundaryMargin: EdgeInsets.all(0.0),
                minScale: 1.0,
                maxScale: 2.5,
                onInteractionEnd: //scale = 1.0,
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can copy paste run full code below 
This is modification of official example of `transformationController` https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/InteractiveViewer/transformationController.html 
Whenever the child is transformed, the `Matrix4` value is updated and all `listeners` are notified. If the value is set, `InteractiveViewer` will update to respect the new value.
You can in `onInteractionEnd` reset animation as official demo do
code snippet

```
void _animateResetInitialize() {
    _controllerReset.reset();
    _animationReset = Matrix4Tween(
      begin: _transformationController.value,
      end: Matrix4.identity(),
    ).animate(_controllerReset);
    _animationReset.addListener(_onAnimateReset);
    _controllerReset.forward();
  }
  
void _onInteractionEnd(ScaleEndDetails details) {
    _animateResetInitialize();
  }
```

working demo

[image]

full code

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

/// This is the main application widget.
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  static const String _title = 'Flutter Code Sample';

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: _title,
      home: MyStatefulWidget(),
    );
  }
}

/// This is the stateful widget that the main application instantiates.
class MyStatefulWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  MyStatefulWidget({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _MyStatefulWidgetState createState() => _MyStatefulWidgetState();
}

/// This is the private State class that goes with MyStatefulWidget.
/// AnimationControllers can be created with `vsync: this` because of TickerProviderStateMixin.
class _MyStatefulWidgetState extends State<MyStatefulWidget>
    with TickerProviderStateMixin {
  final TransformationController _transformationController =
  TransformationController();
  Animation<Matrix4> _animationReset;
  AnimationController _controllerReset;

  void _onAnimateReset() {
    _transformationController.value = _animationReset.value;
    if (!_controllerReset.isAnimating) {
      _animationReset?.removeListener(_onAnimateReset);
      _animationReset = null;
      _controllerReset.reset();
    }
  }

  void _animateResetInitialize() {
    _controllerReset.reset();
    _animationReset = Matrix4Tween(
      begin: _transformationController.value,
      end: Matrix4.identity(),
    ).animate(_controllerReset);
    _animationReset.addListener(_onAnimateReset);
    _controllerReset.forward();
  }

// Stop a running reset to home transform animation.
  void _animateResetStop() {
    _controllerReset.stop();
    _animationReset?.removeListener(_onAnimateReset);
    _animationReset = null;
    _controllerReset.reset();
  }

  void _onInteractionStart(ScaleStartDetails details) {
    // If the user tries to cause a transformation while the reset animation is
    // running, cancel the reset animation.
    if (_controllerReset.status == AnimationStatus.forward) {
      _animateResetStop();
    }
  }

  void _onInteractionEnd(ScaleEndDetails details) {
    _animateResetInitialize();
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _controllerReset = AnimationController(
      vsync: this,
      duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 400),
    );
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _controllerReset.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.primary,
      appBar: AppBar(
        automaticallyImplyLeading: false,
        title: const Text('Controller demo'),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: InteractiveViewer(
          boundaryMargin: EdgeInsets.all(double.infinity),
          transformationController: _transformationController,
          minScale: 1.0,
          maxScale: 2.5,
          onInteractionStart: _onInteractionStart,
          onInteractionEnd: _onInteractionEnd,
          child: Image.network("https://picsum.photos/250?image=9")
        ),
      ),
      persistentFooterButtons: [
        IconButton(
          onPressed: _animateResetInitialize,
          tooltip: 'Reset',
          color: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.surface,
          icon: const Icon(Icons.replay),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! Works great. For multiple images on the same screen would you do all of this repeatedly or can some of this code apply to more than one image?

Comment: @chrisfavritz, could you post your reproduce code to a new question. need to reproduce layout of multiple image. thanks.

Comment: @chunhunghan Simply amazing!

Answer (score 1):

I came up with a simple solution.

Just save the initial controller value on the start of the interaction, then change back to that value when the interaction ends.

```
TransformationController controllerT = TransformationController();
var initialControllerValue;

InteractiveViewer(
    minScale: 1.0,
    maxScale: 100.0,
    transformationController: controllerT,
    onInteractionStart: (details){
        initialControllerValue = controllerT.value;
    },
    onInteractionEnd: (details){
        controllerT.value = initialControllerValue;
    },
...
```

If you want this in a grid or list view, just declare the controller in the itemBuilder:

```
ListView.builder(
    itemCount: widget.types.length,
    itemBuilder: (context, index) {
        TransformationController controllerT = TransformationController();
        var initialControllerValue;
```